# What is best way to structuring my django third party app

Tags: python, django

I've been working a lot with django lately and am trying to capture some common apps and build them into third party package and publish them as open source in github.

My question is, how can I maintain the best practice for doing such thing. Assuming I want to build a third party app called "randomizer"

below are the steps am following

1. Start a project ./manage startproject randomizer_project
2. create the following structure

   - randomizer_project

     - randomizer_project

       - settings.py
       - wsgi.py
     - shared (to be used for creating third party apps)

       - randomizer (**init git here**)

         - randomizer

           - models.py
           - views.py
           - etc
         - README.rst
         - LICENSE
         - setup.py
   - manage.py

and in my settings.py am including shared/randomizer in the python path. Am I following the best approach here? should I keep doing the same? please advise if anyone has been following certain method of work that makes it quicker to build packages and publish them faster.

many thanks,

Comment: I usually place the app in a separate directory and sym-link to it in my 'testing' django app. I find that most time goes into getting the packaging correct with pypi and pip etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django documentation has a nice article on creating reusable apps:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/

And there's a bunch of useful information and links in that article, that can help you in structuring your project/app in most appropriate way (like [this one](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html) for example)

In general I don't think that including every reusable app to the python path is a good practice. IMO the preferred way is to add the app to the INSTALLED_APPS setting, include the app's URLconf to our project urls.py and run syncdb command to create needed models like we do for most existing apps these days.